# setTimeout not delaying -- brackets after function alter for loop count

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/Muffinlord/pen/zdzaZV

```
<html>

<body>
  <style>
    html {
      background-color: black;
    }
    table, tr, td {
      border: 15px solid white;
    }
    td {
      background-color: white;
      height: 26px;
    }
  </style>
  <style id="player">
     {
      background-color: red;
      border: 15px solid red;
}
  </style>
  <style id="evil">
    #id2 {
      background-color: blue;
      border: 15px solid blue;
    }
  </style>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td id="id1">
      </td>
      <td id="id2">
      </td>
      <td id="id3">
      </td>
      <td id="id4">
      </td>
      <td id="id5">
      </td>
      <td id="id6">
      </td>
      <td id="id7">
      </td>
      <td id="id8">
      </td>
      <td id="id9">
      </td>
      <td id="id10">
      </td>
      <td id="id11">
      </td>
      <td id="id12">
      </td>
      <td id="id13">
      </td>
      <td id="id14">
      </td>
      <td id="id15">
      </td>
      <td id="id16">
      </td>
      <td id="id17">
      </td>
      <td id="id18">
      </td>
      <td id="id19">
      </td>
      <td id="id20">
      </td>
      <td id="id21">
      </td>
      <td id="id22">
      </td>
      <td id="id23">
      </td>
      <td id="id24">
      </td>
      <td id="id25">
      </td>
      <td id="id26">
      </td>
      <td id="id27">
      </td>
      <td id="id28">
      </td>
      <td id="id29">
      </td>
      <td id="id30">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="id31">
      </td>
      <td id="id32">
      </td>
      <td id="id33">
      </td>
      <td id="id34">
      </td>
      <td id="id35">
      </td>
      <td id="id36">
      </td>
      <td id="id37">
      </td>
      <td id="id38">
      </td>
      <td id="id39">
      </td>
      <td id="id40">
      </td>
      <td id="id41">
      </td>
      <td id="id42">
      </td>
      <td id="id43">
      </td>
      <td id="id44">
      </td>
      <td id="id45">
      </td>
      <td id="id46">
      </td>
      <td id="id47">
      </td>
      <td id="id48">
      </td>
      <td id="id49">
      </td>
      <td id="id50">
      </td>
      <td id="id51">
      </td>
      <td id="id52">
      </td>
      <td id="id53">
      </td>
      <td id="id54">
      </td>
      <td id="id55">
      </td>
      <td id="id56">
      </td>
      <td id="id57">
      </td>
      <td id="id58">
      </td>
      <td id="id59">
      </td>
      <td id="id60">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="id61">
      </td>
      <td id="id62">
      </td>
      <td id="id63">
      </td>
      <td id="id64">
      </td>
      <td id="id65">
      </td>
      <td id="id66">
      </td>
      <td id="id67">
      </td>
      <td id="id68">
      </td>
      <td id="id69">
      </td>
      <td id="id70">
      </td>
      <td id="id71">
      </td>
      <td id="id72">
      </td>
      <td id="id73">
      </td>
      <td id="id74">
      </td>
      <td id="id75">
      </td>
      <td id="id76">
      </td>
      <td id="id77">
      </td>
      <td id="id78">
      </td>
      <td id="id79">
      </td>
      <td id="id80">
      </td>
      <td id="id81">
      </td>
      <td id="id82">
      </td>
      <td id="id83">
      </td>
      <td id="id84">
      </td>
      <td id="id85">
      </td>
      <td id="id86">
      </td>
      <td id="id87">
      </td>
      <td id="id88">
      </td>
      <td id="id89">
      </td>
      <td id="id90">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    </body>

    </html>
    <script>
      var playerorig = document.getElementById("player").innerHTML;
      for (i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
        setTimeout(fixtimeout, 100);
      }
      function fixtimeout() {
        document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = "#id" + (90 - i) + playerorig;
        console.log(player);
      }
    </script>
```

Sorry for the messy code.

The table's bottom row is supposed to turn red one cell at a time until the one cell reaches the bottom left hand side. (each cell turns white again apart from the last)

This is supposed to happen with a 0.1 second delay between them.
If I have brackets after fixtimeout in the setTimeout on line 223 the for loop ends at the second last cell.

I have no idea why the delay isnt happening and the for loop is being affected. Please help

Comment: calling setTimeout 29 times in a row with the same 100ms delay means after 100ms they will all execute (after one another, but that execution doesn't take long)

Comment: This is a very common duplicate.

Comment: You didn't think maybe a shorter piece of representative HTML would've gotten the idea across, rather than 90 td elements that all took two lines, and a bunch of irrelevant CSS?

Comment: `setTimeout(fixtimeout, 100 * (i + 1))`

Comment: yeah 2.5 hours of sleep, should have removed the unnecessary tables. and ty for the explanation. makes a lot of sense